# link to services without specifying a port

Tags: service, proxy, hyperlink, ip, port

I am a beginner IT specialist, please help me understand this problem. I have a virtual machine with a static public IP address. Let's say 177.17.16.15. And there is a purchased domain name, for example - example.com. GitLab is installed on this virtual machine, which by default occupied ports 80 and 443, and at first example.com redirected me to the GitLab main page, then I found the setting right in the web interface, where I gave it the name gitlab.example.com and it worked. Now I have jenkins running on port 8022 because port 80 was taken over by Gitlab. That is, to get to jenkins I need to register 177.17.16.15:8022. In the settings, in the web interface, I found that I could give it a domain name like jenkins.example.com, but it didn’t work because they would redirect me to gitlab.example.com. If I explicitly add the port at the end of the link, I can get to jenkins - jenkins.example.com:8022. Is it possible to change the settings somewhere so that I get to Jenkins via the link jenkins.example.com, without specifying the port? There is no nginx and no apache on the virtual machine; I could not understand how the jenkins and gitlab web interfaces work. My jenkins also builds a website running in a docker container on port 8011 (8011:80), that is, I can see the web page of this site at 177.17.16.15:2011. I tried to configure nginx inside the docker container, but I couldn’t change anything, I need this site to work directly on the domain name - example.com. What to do? how to configure a link in the format service.example.com for each port?

I tried to configure redirection, but I don’t understand how to do it correctly and where the configuration files are located

Comment: Hello, this is barely readable. You should start by looking at what paragraphs do. Adding some other formatting could also help.